# Prove $A-I $ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, matrix-equations

If A=($a_{ij}$) is a nxn matrix of real numbers such that $\sum_j^n$ $a_{ij}$=1 for each *i*, show that the matrix A-I is not invertible. I am not very good at proofs and have previously heard you cannot prove a negative so I am wondering if this is solvable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean the sum from $j=1$ to $n$ is equal 1, i.e. the matrix is stochastic. If this is the case, consider what happens when you multiply $A-I$ by a vector where all entries are one.
Certainly it is not true that you cannot prove a negative statement.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what you mean about "can't prove a negative"; there are numerous negative statements that can be proven.

Here's a hint for this problem: a square matrix $B$ is not invertible if and only if there is a nonzero $x$ such that $Bx=0$. Consider $B=A-I$. By multiplying it out you find that $Bx$ is a vector whose $i$th component is $\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} x_j$. Since you subtract a $1$ in each row, $\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} = 0$ for every $i$. So can you choose $x_j$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} x_j = \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} = 0$?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you are saying that, along the diagonal of the _n_x_n_ matrix every number is 0, with all other numbers being equal to 1 (from a_{ij}=1). In the case of b_{ij} (from B=A-I) x_j has to be 1. However doesn't that just make the matrix b_{ij}=0 only when _i=j_

Comment: No, you aren't reading correctly. Being explicit: $\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij} = \left ( \sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^n a_{ij} \right ) + b_{ii} = \left ( \sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^n a_{ij} \right ) a_{ii} - 1 = \left ( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \right ) - 1 = 1-1=0$. We don't know what any of the individual entries of the matrices are, all we know is the row sums.

Comment: So following through (A-I)C=I has no possible C that can make A-I into an identity matrix because any _nxn_ matrix where $\sum_j^n$ $a_{ij}$=1 will have a determinant of 0 and thus be singular.

Comment: @James That works. An easier way to see it is that you can't uniquely define $(A-I)^{-1} (0)$: certainly zero is a candidate, but so is the nonzero $x$ that we constructed!